# Security JDBC and Google Apps Scripts

Tags: ssl, jdbc, google-apps-script

I have a security related question on JDBC Service.

How secure is the JDBC connection between Google Scripts and a remote database?
There's any way to configure SSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no access to the Java truststore  to be able to generate a client certificate, I don't see how this would be possible.

As far as how secure the connection is, if you are using firewall rules to allow only Google servers to your jdbc port:

```
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8
```

On your mysql server set up the user's host component to also only allow those ip ranges, and set a secure certificate size password just in case.

Man in the middle attacks would be the only real security concern you have, not sure these days how likely a MIM attack would be....

Comment: These are all google assigned address space blocks, not just "servers". It's like securing only one door in a house, leaving all other open.

Comment: It should now be possible to do this as google has added advanced parameters to the connect function. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getConnection(String,Object)