# SSL properties in URL parameter of JDBC connection in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://<ip-address>:<port>/<db>?user=<user>&password=<password>&useSSL=true');
```

I get the following error message when trying to make the above connection: "The following connection properties are unsupported: useSSL"

My hunch is that SSL is not supported at all for JDBC in GAS, but I just wanted to verify since there is nothing in the docs that describe using User and Password URL properties with the above type of syntax, even though it allows me to make connections like this (the above works without the useSSL property). I took the useSSL property from the MySQL Connector/J docs thinking there might be some sort of general standard for using JDBC drivers, even if not fully documented in GAS.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Somebody mentioned in another post [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642496/security-jdbc-and-google-apps-scripts) that the Java truststore wouldn't be accessible from Google Apps Script, "thus not enabling the ability to generate certificates". As far as I know, I can generate certificates and keys where ever, I just need a place to store them (possibly remotely when using GAS JDBC) and a way to point to them (url property that is valid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only connection parameters currently supported are those listed in the "Advanced Parameters" section of the [`Jdbc.getConnection()` docs](https://devsite.googleplex.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getConnection%28String,Object%29).

We currently have a whitelist of connection parameters we support, and it's possible we could add support or useSSL. Please file a feature request on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) and we'll consider it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Eric,
created an issue here, to be starred.

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3944

Comment: In case anyone finds themselves here wondering how this all turned out, the referenced issue above has been resolved, skip forward to comment #18 for a good example, and thanks again @eric-koleda!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528221/how-to-connect-to-database-with-ssl-in-google-apps-script/49524119