# Error connecting to RDS Mysql using SSL from Google Apps script

Tags: mysql, ssl, jdbc, google-apps-script, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to Mysql instance in AWS RDS using SSL from Google Apps script. I have been searching similar questions here for the past 2 days, but no luck finding a solution.

For RDS, since only the Server certificate from Amazon is available (rds-combined-ca-bundle) and no client key/cert, I have given that in the _serverSslCertificate parameter. The credentials are correct. It works from other tools like SequelPro.
RDS security group has all the [Google's servers][1].

But apps script keeps failing with "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."

Here is my code

```
var address = 'hostname:3306'; 
var user = 'xxxx'; 
var userPwd = 'yyyy'; 
var db = 'zzzz'; 
var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db ;    

var serverSslCertificate = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem");


var serverSslCert = serverSslCertificate.getContentText();
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, 
                            {user:user, 
                             password: userPwd,
                             _serverSslCertificate: serverSslCert
                            }); 


var stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

Can someone please share a working example? Or is this an issue? 
Appreciate your valuable response, thanks!

Comment: are you sure you whitelisted all the Google ips?

Comment: yes, I have added all the Google ips to RDS security group for port 3306

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528221/how-to-connect-to-database-with-ssl-in-google-apps-script). You need to add `useSSL=true` in the query string of your connection URL.