# GAS MySQL SSL connection

Tags: mysql, ssl, google-apps-script

I want to connect via Jdbc.getConnection() with my Google Cloud MySQL db and use SSL.

Within GAS: I have made the exact same setup as described in this [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524119/5160136), but I get the error message: "Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

```
conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/myDBname?useSSL=true', {
    'user': settings.user,
    'password': settings.userPwd,
    '_serverSslCertificate': '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----super_secret_1-----END CERTIFICATE-----',
    '_clientSslCertificate': '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----super_secret_2-----END CERTIFICATE-----',
    '_clientSslKey': '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----super_secret_3-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
});
```

Did something change over the years?

What I have tried so far:

1. The user and password seems to be correct, because without "?useSSL=true" everything works
2. I have also created new SSL certificates within GCP
3. Unfortunately Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection() is not an option to use instead Jdbc.getConnection()
4. Runtime V8 and Stable/Rhino throw the same error

Answer (score 1):

Cause for the issue: Within the certificate and key strings the "\n" are missing.
These are not inserted within the GCP SQL modal when a new SSL certificate was created. So you need to download client-key.pem, client-cert.pem and server-ca.pem and replace each line break with a "\n".